# Email Template builder like Mailchmip

Tags: php, email, jquery-plugins, html-email, mailchimp

i want to edit email templates like mailchimp, is there any jQuery plugin available which is similar to email builder like mailchimp, which i can integrate in my php application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's called jQuery drag and drop template builder:

http://simbyone.com/drag-and-drop-newsletter-builder-using-jquery/

Answer (score 10):

Look at this http://mosaico.io/, it's open source in github https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico

Also this one [beeFree](https://beefree.io/) is a good product, and actively developed