# Email templates for Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, web, outlook

I'm searching for an email template builder that will support every mail (even outlook), or some tips how it should be done to support every mail.

Now I am able to do an responsive Web email for Gmail but when I send it to Outlook mailbox it looks disgusting.

Comment: You can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336481/email-template-builder-like-mailchmip but to be honest, emails matters is not easy to implement, I'm suffering from this issue! + which outlook version you want? also take a look here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

There are services such as Campaign Monitor and Dotmailer that do hybrid templates you create using drag and drop feature on their platform. If you code HTML it will make it easier to edit and manipulate the HTML which ever way you want. Both platforms use hybrid method of coding. I wrote about this in SO documentation (information now in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096905/trying-to-get-email-to-collapse-at-responsive-column-points-using-zurb-foundatio/42132424#42132424)) which can be of help. If you need my help please let me know.