# How to make HTML table responsive for email template when using an external CSS file is not a possibility

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-tables, email-templates

I created an email template that uses a two-column layout. This was my approach:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <h1>Header of my email template</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <p>Footer of my email template</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It works great on desktop! I have a two-column layout exactly as I wanted it. The problem is on phones because screens are too small for a two-column layout. I need one picture per row, not two, for mobile devices. What I could do is to use `float:left;width:100%` for the `<td>` elements that contain the images so that I have the one column layout that I need. However, that `float:left;width:100%` should apply only when `@media screen and (max-width:450px)` for example. But there is no way to use `@media screen and (max-width:450px)` using inline CSS. Remember, this is for an email template. So I cannot invoke external CSS files or add CSS to the `<head>` of the page because this is code that will be sent for an email template.

I found at https://kb.benchmarkemail.com/using-css-in-html-emails/ this advice, but that is not a solution for responsive tables:

> Things To Do
>
> Use tables for layout. Tables are more consistently supported. We
>   recommend that you place your CSS code inline to your content. It
>   should look something like this: Your content
>   here.... Declare width, cellpadding, and cellspacing for all
>   tables and table cells. This will result in a fixed width for the
>   template. Use hspace and vspace tag attributes to add whitespace
>   around an image. Margin and padding inline styles are supported by
>   most, but not all email clients

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What is the app you are using in mobile? gmail supports @media: https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css

Comment: @A.Meshu I see that https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css provides an example where `<style>` is inside of `<head>`. The problem is that the email template that I am writing only sends a `<table>` assuming it will go straight to the `<body>` of the email. I am not inserting anything into `<head>`. Should my email template be `<html><head></head><body><table>..........</table></body></html>` instead of just the `<table>..........</table>` that I am sending?

Comment: Actually you don't need `<head>`, just add it on `<style>` element before `<table`>. (modarn) Browsers automatically renders the correct tree.

Comment: @A.Meshu Wow! That sounds amazing. So instead of `<table>..........</table>` I just need `<style>..........</style><table>..........</table>` and that is it?

Comment: WAIT! You will still need to do the inline style for outlook but for gmail it should work...

Comment: @A.Meshu I know. Of course I will have this: `<style>.class and/or #id elements for responsive table</style><table>My table invokes the corresponding id or class properties that I defined in the <style> area...</table>`. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually you can't override inline style properties from the `style` element. `!important` doesn't work all time. ie if you set: `#demo {width: 100px;}` from `style` and then use inline style ie: `<div id="demo" style="width: 150px;">` this element will probably spans for 150px.

Comment: @A.Meshu I do not even plan to override anything. If `<style>.....</style><table>.....</table>` works, then all of my CSS will be in `<style>.....</style>` and in `<table>.....</table>` I will only invoke CSS written in `<style>.....</style>`, not write inline CSS at all, if in fact the styles can be written in `<style>.....</style>` as you suggested. Can you please confirm this?

Comment: I can confirm 99% that it would work on gmail app. not on desktop!

Comment: @A.Meshu Amazing! I will test it in the next few minutes/hours and once I confirm it works, I will come back to let you know and see if you can officially write this as an answer to mark it as accepted so that hopefully this can be useful to other people :) Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210831/discussion-between-jaime-montoya-and-a-meshu).

Comment: @A.Meshu It does not work. I used `<style>
@media screen and (max-width:450px) {
    .responsive {
        float:left!important;
        width:100%!important
    }
}
</style><table><tr><td class="responsive">.........</td></tr>.........</table>`. But it is not working. I am 100% sure my CSS is good because when I use the CSS inline code `float:left!important;width:100%!important`, my responsive design works. So it is just the `<style></style>` that is not being recognized. Does it work for you? You were 99% that it would work on Gmail app. I am using Gmail app. How do you make it work?

Comment: I was 99% sure that this would work since i was copy-paste myself the @media example from the link i provided to you and and it worked...

Comment: @A.Meshu Very strange. How can this work for you but not for me? I will examine what the community says about it.

Comment: @A.Meshu I had to use `<html><head><style type="text/css">..........</style></head><body>...........</body></html>` as I mentioned in my answer to my own question. Only `<style> @media screen and (max-width:450px) { .responsive { float:left!important; width:100%!important } } </style><table><tr><td class="responsive">.........</td></tr>.........</table>` did not work in my case. I had to start with `<html>` and have `<styles>` within the `<head>` element as it is normally done in any HTML document. Thank you for helping me to figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google offers CSS support: https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css as A. Meshu pointed out in his comments to my question.

I found at  https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/ that they say this:

> "You can leave the media query styles in the `<head>` of your email, as
>   clients that support media queries don’t strip out the `<head>` or
>   `<style>` areas."

That made me think I had to send a complete `<HTML>` document, so I even included `<html><head><style type="text/css">..........</style></head><body>...........</body></html>`.

For my other email templates I just send code for the `<body>`. I start the template with a `<div>` and everything works. But for this template now I am using this structure:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width:450px) {
    .responsive {
        float:left!important;
        width:100%!important
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
..........
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to A. Meshu for providing very important hints in his comments to my question to figure it out.

Comment: Try hybrid coding, you don't even need media query to make emails responsive.

Comment: @Syfer Not sure what you mean by "hybrid coding".

Comment: There is a method of coding that is not dependent on media queries to stack blocks/elements in mobile. The method of coding is called hybrid/spongy. You can see how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096905/trying-to-get-email-to-collapse-at-responsive-column-points-using-zurb-foundatio/42132424#42132424)

Comment: @Syfer Interesting. I hope it is cross-platform (compatible for all clients and web browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Since `table` elements are block-level, I would say to change those `td`s into nested `table`s like it's 1999, and then `float` the first one left:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <h1>Header of my email template</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="float:left;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <p>Footer of my email template</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```